# registerNib for UICollectionElementKindCell does't work when using presentViewController animated: false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionviewcell, presentviewcontroller

I register the `registerNib` method in `viewWillAppear()` and when I use `presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`, it works fine.

But when I use `presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)`, it doesn't work.

**Error** message is following. Do I have to register on storyboard? can't register by program?

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'could not dequeue a view of    
kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier NoContentsCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set reusable identifier in your storyborad.

[image]

and use `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`

For register class

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"menuCell")
```

For register nib

```
var nib=UINib(nibName: "MenuCell", bundle:nil)
collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "menuCell")
```

may you get help from this

Comment: thank you @ashish-kakkad
I know this way. but I want to know why it doesn't work well when using presentViewController animated: false

Comment: @naohide put this code in view did load or view will appear

Comment: I used it in view did load, it works clear. Thank you so much!